# Making Calendar on symfony2 and FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony

I am planning to make Calendar function on symfony2 and FOSUserBundle.

Ideally,
Events in calendar are  stored mysql database through doctrine2.

I have searched some plugins

[CalendarBundle](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle)

It is no longer maintained.

[FrequenceWebCalendRBundle](http://knpbundles.com/frequence-web/FrequenceWebCalendRBundle)

I can not make it work.

Could you suggest me any good way to make calendar like scheduler on symfony2?

it seems that there is not conclusive or major solution on symfony2 .
So,I am wondering.

I appriceate your advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I use this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/. It is open source licensed under an MIT license. To store information about a event, here are its properties: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/. Use json for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a really quick integration go with [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) and [jQuery's FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

Advantage: API methods already there - just use them if you don't want to start from scratch.

If you want Ajax JSON requests to fill the calendar try the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle).

Comment: Thank you for your advice,I am using jquery's fullCalendar with mysql.
I am succeed in showing data from Databse.But it is not possible to add ,cancel or edit from Calendar?For now,I put event data to database from other  script.

Comment: I found articles on their web site -- DISCLAIMER: FullCalendar is great for displaying events, but it isn't a complete solution for event content-management. Beyond dragging an event to a different time/day, you cannot change an event's name or other associated data. It is up to you to add this functionality through FullCalendar's event hooks.

Comment: I think I have to make data input UI by myself.I will try thanks alot @nifr